# Only GET '/' route is working in my MERN project, testing with POSTMAN getting 404 responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, mern

My app.js looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
var cors = require('cors');

const fruits = require('./routes/api/fruits');

const app = express();

connectDB();

app.use(cors({origin: true, credentails: true}));

app.use(express.json({extended: false}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));

app.use('/api/fruits', fruits);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

My fruit.js in routes/api/fruits.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Fruit = require('../../models/Fruit');

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('fruit route testing!');
    console.log('Route found');
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Fruit.find()
        .then(fruits => res.json(fruits))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nofruitsfound : 'No Fruit Found'}));
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Fruit.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(fruit => res.json(fruit))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({nofruitsfound : 'No Fruit Found'}));
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    Fruit.create(req.body)
        .then(fruit => res.json({ mgs: 'Fruit added sucessfully'}))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unable to add this fruit'}));
});

router.put(':/id', (req, res) => {
    Fruit.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
        .then(fruit => res.json({ mgs: 'Updated successfully'}))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unable to update the Database'}));
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Fruit.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, req.body)
        .then(fruit => res.json({ mgs: 'Fruit deleted sucessfully'}))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ error: 'Unable to find fruit by Id and delete'}));
});

module.exports = router;
```

http://localhost:8082/ gets "Hello World"

http://localhost:8082/api/fruit/test gets:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /test</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried http://localhost:8082/api/fruits/test is working but POST for http://localhost:8082/api/fruits/ is getting {"error":"Unable to add this fruit"}

[postman request for POST http://localhost:8082/api/fruits/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGyLN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this line `app.use('/api/fruits.', fruits);` you have defined a base path for the endpoints/routes in the `fruits.js` file. What this means is that for you to be able access the routes you have to prefix the base path to the url as follows:

`http://localhost:8082/api/fruits/test` - will get the `/test` route

`http://localhost:8082/api/fruits` - will get all fruits as defined in fruits.js

`http://localhost:8082/api/fruits` - used with a POST request you can create a new fruit.

Your base path plus host is then this: `http://localhost:8082/api/fruits`

Looks like you are new to Express.js so I am going to add this:

`app.use(express.json({extended: false}));` - This line tells express to handle request body in JSON only. So in Postman or any other HTTP client you are using, ensure the body for your POST requests are JSON.

Comment: That was very helpful!
I got the /test working and got the response "fruit route testing!"
Still not getting the creation of fruit working on the post "/"

Comment: For the POST use same endpoint as the one I specified for the GET in the answer.

Comment: I put a picture in the original post for the POST http://localhost:8082/api/fruits/ as I am getting {"error":"Unable to add this fruit"}

Comment: Adding a picture is an entirely different technique as the base express doesn't handle file, so you will need a library that supports multipart encoding like the multer package.

Comment: No sorry, I'm not adding a picture in my project. I mean I added a picture ^^^ in my post on stackover flow.

Comment: In your picture, if you take a look alongside where you have the radio buttons you will see a dropdown with `Text` selected, change that to JSON and it should work. Body parser handles url-encoded form data and json

Comment: yeah i agree. this is likely because the headers doesnt contain a content-type of application/json therefore your body parser is not picking up anything in the body. Anything after that is between you and your data finding function

Answer (score 0):

you have neither `/test` or `/api/test` defined. `/api/fruit/test` would be the closest you have with the endpoints with a `:id` parameter.

Be aware though you have a `.` character where your express app is consuming your `/api/fruit` route. It says `/api/fruit.`

Comment: Okay I fixed the "." in the app/fruit.

I'm still a bit unsure of the testing with PostMan. I'll add a screenshot to the OG post so you can see what I'm trying.